# Sourceconversion: Remove all "using" declarations, replace full qualified type name in source

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

While writing code using is fine and avoids blobbed code. 
While inspecting third party code, with lots of namespaces referenced, the code analyst is not familiar with, this need is inverted.

Ideally there would be a configuration list, where I can check, which namespaces should be converted in such way.

Is there a tool in Visual Studio or external, that removes all "using" declarations of namespaces, and qualifies each typerefrence in the sourcecode by it's fully qualified classname?

Inverted feature whould be a bonus.

Comment: Be aware that due to aliases, this may not always be possible. E.g. in some circumstances, code may be utilizing two (or more) distinct types with identical fully-qualified names.

Comment: If there are so many 'using' statements that reading the code is difficult, it may be an indication that the class is doing too much.